# NET6 Blazor application and authentication with Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, blazor

I'm trying to add to my Blazor server and client the authentication with Azure Active Directory. I created a new `App Registration` in `Azure`

[image]

and copied the *Tenant ID* and *Client ID* in my *appconfig.json* that now looks like

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mycompany.com",
    "TenantId": "xxx",
    "ClientId": "xxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/authentication/login-callback"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

also I setup this *Platform configurations*

[image]

Now, I run the server application and I can do the authentication with my user. After the authentication, I get this error

[image]

My organization `b4e49ba2-xxx` is not related at all with the organization mentioned in the error. I created a new `App Registration` few times with the same result.

This is the App permissions screen

[image]

Comment: Does ENRICO UI app has a Service principal created? like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/ZlTNHBA.png)

Comment: No, I haven't created a `Service principal`

Comment: I have other applications that are working without the `Service principal`

Comment: I tried to replicate the same issue with my personal account and I could replicate the problem.

Comment: The error message states the ENRICOUI app is trying to access ErcenkSaaS Spa app. So the ErcenkSaaS Spa app resides in your tenant?

Comment: So its a multitenant app?

Comment: Not at all. I have no idea who this ErcenkSaaS Spa is. The funny thing is using my personal Azure account I get the same message.

Comment: https://github.com/erossini/BlazorADAccess here you have the code using my personal account (completely different from the other one). I get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255661/discussion-between-rukmini-and-enrico).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error usually occurs if you have not created the API application and trying to access the API.

**To resolve the error,** create the Sever app and expose an API like below:

[image]

In the Client App, add the API permissions like below:

[image]

Make sure to update scopes in `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("api://ServerClientID/access_as_user");
});
```

[image]

To resolve the error "***The 'scope' or 'scp' claim does not contain scopes 'api://xxx/ScopeName' or was not found*.**", make sure to update **scope as scope name** not `api://ServerappId/scopename` in ADTest.Server **appsettings.json**:

```json
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "TenantID",
    "ClientId": "ClientID",
    "CallbackPath": "/authentication/login-callback",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user" //scopename
  },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

[image]

**I am able to login to Blazor app and fetch the data successfully:**

[image]