# Call an API from a Blazor application both protected with Microsoft Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm building an application with Blazor Web Assembly hosted in an ASP.NET Core application. Based from scratch and the boilerplate from Visual Studio, I created the solution.

In another solution I have a web API build with ASP.NET Core (I will call them *External API*). This application has its own URL and registration in the `App Registration` in the Azure portal. From Swagger, I can access the APIs and their are protected by the Microsoft authentication.

In the same `Tenant ID`, I created 2 new app registrations for the Blazor Server and the Blazor WebAssembly. The UI can connect to the Active Directory in order to authenticate the users and the Web Assembly can call the APIs in the server project. For more details about it, see my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77315993/net6-blazor-application-and-authentication-with-azure-active-directory).

I define the API like the following code

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public class CurrenciesController : ControllerBase
{
    // omit the constructor and the injection
    // AzureAd:Scopes is "User.Read"

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAd:Scopes")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(List<Currency>))]
    public ActionResult GetCurrencies()
    {
        return Ok(repo.GetCurrencies());
    }
}
```

Now, my problem is from the Web Assembly to call the External API. In the *Program.cs* I added

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<MiddletierApiAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Middletier.UI.ServerAPI", client => 
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Middletier.API", client => 
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:50441"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<MiddletierApiAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => 
    sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
      .CreateClient("Middletier.UI.ServerAPI"));

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => 
    sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
      .CreateClient("Middletier.API"));

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);

    // this is for the Blazor Server
    options.ProviderOptions
           .DefaultAccessTokenScopes
           .Add("api://544b368d-xxx/user.access");
});
```

The `MiddletierApiAuthorizationMessageHandler` implementation is this one

```
public class MiddletierApiAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public MiddletierApiAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider,
        NavigationManager navigationManager)
        : base(provider, navigationManager)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(
            authorizedUrls: new[] { "https://localhost:7575" },
            // External API
            scopes: new[] { "api://d3de6da4-xxx/User.Read" });
    }
}
```

Then, in a Razor page I added

```
@inject IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory

@code {
    private Currency[]? currencies;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient("Middletier.API");
            currencies = await httpClient
                                  .GetFromJsonAsync<Currency[]>("/api/v1/Currencies");
        }
        catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException exception)
        {
            exception.Redirect();
        }
    }
}
```

The call is always `401 (Unauthorized)`. I added CORS. What do I miss?

Comment: use the same configuration in the external API as the configuration in the hosted asp.net core.

Comment: I'm doing some tests. asap I have an answer

Comment: could you pls let me know if you had any update on it?

Answer (score 0):

In your external API project, you should have configurations in appsettings.json like this:

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "ClientId": "client_id",
  "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
  "Domain": "tenant_id",
  "TenantId": "tenant_id",
  "Audience": "api://client_id"
},
```

And in the program.cs,

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

In the Controller, add `[Authorize]` attribute.

The fields should be filled based on the access token generated by the blazor wasm client. Let's say in the blazor wsam client app, we use aad app which client id is "id_A" to do the authentication and use scope `api://id_A/api_permission_name` to do the authorization. Then we would get an access token with `scp` claim which value contains `api://id_A/api_permission_name` and `appid` claim which value is `id_A`. Then filling the fields in the external API project with `id_A`.

[image]

==========================

401 is unauthorized error, it usually happened when we used a wrong access token. Normally speaking, when we have an API project which is protected by Azure AD, then we should use an access token which matches the configurations in the configuration we set inside appsettings.json, like what I explained above. If the value we set doesn't match the vaule inside the access token, then 401 would occur.

Here's Azure AD [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#web-api). We all know that there're 2 types of API permissions, delegated and application. If we set in the API project like what I said above, then access token containing both correct `roles` claim or correct `scp` claim would work. But the client id must be the same. I'm afraid the client id you set in your external api project is not the same as the one you set in your blazor wasm project.