# Securing an Azure REST API, why isn't it this simple?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-webapps

I have been looking around to secure my Azure Web API in a way that seems impossible, but I don't really know why it should be impossible, so I guess I have simple missed something.

### This is what I want to do.

1. Create a Azure Web API site.
2. Create an 'Application' for this API
3. Create 2 roles in this 'Application'

[image]

4. Use this 'Application' information and add an AzureAd section to my API's settings-file.
   [image]
5. Tell the API to use this 'Application' to authenticate/authorize and calls to the API by adding the following to the program.cs file.

[image]

[image]

6. In my controllers I add the attributes to enabled the authorization

[image]

[image]

7. In the 'Enterprise Application' that is referenced to my 'Application' add users to the roles that is created in my 'Application'

[image]

And that is all I is needed to do to be able to call my endpoints that is marked with the 'reader' Role, as long as I am logged in, and if I am not I need to login first. If I need another apps or api to call this api, they can be added to the 'Reader' role, by simple adding there system.identity to the 'Reader' role, and it will simple work, no need to use any token and stuff.

Is this impossible to achive or have I simple missed somthing, because it seems way more complex to implement authentication/authorizaten to a API than this, and also be able to call it.

If I create a webapp, I can more or less use this approche to secury my webapp UI, but I can't get it to work in the same way for an API.

Comment: AFAIK, your implementation looks fine. Is there anything you want to achieve?

Comment: The problem is that if I implement it like this, and simple try to call the api I will allways get an 401, since I don't send any token and stuff. I want  to get a simple login popup if I isn't logged in, and if I logged in, it simply check if my logged in user is part of the Role.
Basically the same as if I hade try to access an web-site instead of an api....

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77315993/net6-blazor-application-and-authentication-with-azure-active-directory/77317188#77317188?