# Azure ad connection Client MVC C#/ angular 14 - Api netcore v7/8

Tags: angular, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to connect an MVC C#/Angular 14 client to a Netcore 7/8 API via Azure AD, as shown in the screenshots below, the client-side integration is ok.
When I submit the received bearer token to an API endpoint I always get a 401/403 error, can anyone help me at this point?

[image: Client id - Tenant id]
[image: Authentication]
[image: Certificates & secrets]
[image: API permissions]
[image: Expose an API]
[image: Api configs]
[image: Client configs]

[image: Postman params]
[image: New aparms]

I need the api to validate and authenticate the token received from the client

Comment: **To resolve the error** in your case make sure to grant Admin consent to the Demo-app Api permission as admin consent is required.

Comment: Using postman to get token I receive this response {
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid. Trace ID: 889ac41a-5844-4610-8d48-f43fa6a73800 Correlation ID: 855bdb84-1b95-481a-baac-08d62991f6f5 Timestamp: 2023-11-30 16:09:56Z",
    "error_codes": [
        9002313
    ],
    "timestamp": "2023-11-30 16:09:56Z",
    "trace_id": "889ac41a-5844-4610-8d48-f43fa6a73800",
    "correlation_id": "855bdb84-1b95-481a-baac-08d62991f6f5",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"
}

Comment: Can you paste the parameters you are passing to generate token?

Comment: Did you grant admin consent to the API permission?

Comment: I add in question

Comment: What error are you getting after granting the admin consent and executing the code?

Comment: In the postman screenshot you pasted I can see that you have not passed the TenantID value `https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token` and not passed the code value

Comment: Same error using https://login.microsoftonline.com/3105f2ea-*****/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: The code param on Postman, how I get it?

Comment: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=clientid
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=redirecturi
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://xxx/scopename
&state=12345` edit the endpoint based on your values and run it in the browser and sign-in. Code will be generated.

Comment: I received token when I put api://6284dc72-***/.default as scope param  but I try access the api using this token return 401.

Comment: Did you execute the code?

Comment: Yes, I was run code

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

The error ***"401 or 403 unauthorized"*** usually occurs if the access token doesn't contain the required scope to perform the action.

I created an Azure AD application and added API permission:

[image]

I generated **access token** via Postman using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:api://ClientID/api.access
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I tried to access the API, I got the 401 error:

```json
GET https://xxxx/weatherforecast
```

[image]

**To resolve the error** in your case make sure to grant Admin consent to the Demo-app Api permission as admin consent is required.

Make sure that the user must have **Global Administrator or Application Administrator** role to grant admin consent.

[image]

Now **I generated the access token again and I am able to access the Api** successfully:

```json
GET https://xxxx/weatherforecast
```

[image]

Decode the access token and make sure that the **scope is displayed** via [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) :

[image]

**Reference:**

[c# - NET6 Blazor application and authentication with Azure Active Directory - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77315993/net6-blazor-application-and-authentication-with-azure-active-directory/77317188#77317188) by me